# There a quick way to add prefixes to all CSS classes & ID's?

Tags: php, css, regex, css-selectors

I need to quickly add prefixes to all of of my classes and ID's and it's quite a large CSS file. I was thinking a quick regex string but so far I've failed. Any ideas?

I've tried simple things like:

```
\#([A-z0-9]+) {
```

Which will let me replace with #prefix_$1 but it doesn't take into account:

```
#id {
#id.class
#id,
```

etc. I can't just replace all #[a-z0-9] because it will attempt to grab background-colors and so on.

I also need to replace all the classes, which is even more confusing for me.

Comment: regex is not a CSS parser, so you will fail with regex if you can't find a real strict string pattern therein, which is not easy to say if you don't share your whole CSS. Maybe renaming the classes inside the HTML is easier than renaming them inside the CSS?

Comment: @hakre I'd still have to rename the classes and ID's to keep the styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search:

`\.(-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[^}]+{`

`\#(-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[^}]+{`

Should find all your class names and id names

With RegExr, use this:

`(?<=#|\.)(-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(?=[^}]+{)`

Edit:
Here's a link to a test on google's CSS
http://regexr.com?2ugv1

Comment: Which will also match `background: #FFF024;`

Comment: Still -1, will also match the {, causing the css to lose it's curly brackets.

Comment: Why would it match the `{`? The `{` is outside of the `()`

Comment: I don't know, but it does. test it yourself.

Comment: What are you using to test it?

Comment: @RikudoSennin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2746/discussion-between-rob-and-rikudo-sennin)

Comment: I adjusted my solution, the last regexp should work the way you want it.

Comment: it doesn't work for my CSS.. http://regexr.com?332u1, it drops the last character for many of classes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this `[#|\.][\w]+\.?([\w\-]+\s?)` it worked on these

```
#id {
#id.class {
#id, #otherId {
#class-dashed
#class_dashed
ul li:after {content: " #id.class { ";}
.class {background-color:     #fff250}
#id.class {color:#ff}
```

Also found a good [tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to play around with different options. There will still be a problem with the colors, but you can't really get rid of that since they follow the same rules as the ids.

**update**
excluding the `:` from the results to not match colours.

`(?<![: ])[#\.][\w]+\.?([\w-]+\s?)` you'll need a regex engine that supports negative lookbehind, not that familiar with php so don't know if it has it, but I would imagine it does.

Comment: No need for `|` inside of `[]`. Also, failed on `#class-dashed` which is perfectly valid. Also, catches the `{` and removes it. Tested with your own tool.

Comment: -1, will also replace `ul li:after {content: " #id.class { ";}`

Comment: Not a way to exclude ":" from the results?

Comment: @Talasan Nicholson: yeah with negative lookbehind, see update above.

Comment: I've been all over the internet, and this is the only regex that I found that actually works! Well done mate. @MattiLyra

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in my stylesheet with all the cases i have;

Find

```
([\.])([^\d][a-z0-9-_]+[^{])
```

Replace

```
$1prefix .$2
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with something like this:

```
/([#\.])([^\d][a-z0-9-_]+)/ Replace with
$1PREFIX_$2
```

However beware that it would catch colors as well, (if done with lowercase letters) I'm working on a workaround right now.

Comment: -1, will also replace `ul li:after {content: " #id.class { ";}`