# Use regex to add prefixes to HTML classes & ID's?

Tags: php, html, regex

Kind of an add-on to: [There a quick way to add prefixes to all CSS classes & ID's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152185/there-a-quick-way-to-add-prefixes-to-all-css-classes-ids)

I need to find and replace strings like:

```
id="xyz"
```

to replace them to id="prefix_xyz"

This becomes tricky with:

```
class="one two three"
```

where they all still need a prefix. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html "If you parse HTML with regex you are giving in to Them and their blasphemous ways which doom us all to inhuman toil for the One whose Name cannot be expressed in the Basic Multilingual Plane, he comes."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do so by search and replace for all `id` and `class` values [Demo](http://codepad.org/b4h0NpnY):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);

$res = $xpath->query('//@class|//@id');
foreach($res as $attr)
{
    $value = explode(' ', $attr->value);
    foreach($value as &$set)
    {
        $set = 'prefix_'.trim($set);
    }
    unset($set);
    $attr->value = implode(' ', $value);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Seems to be doing strange things to my HTML as well as replacing.. <div class="prefix_cls"/>&#xD; for example.

Comment: Any idea for the above issue?

Comment: What do you mean? Which issue? HTML in, HTML out. Which encoding are you using?